# servers with different hard drive sizes scenario

Tags: mongodb

my scenario is that i have for example 2 servers (shards) one with a bigger hard drive than the other. So if one is 500GB and the other is 1TB and the first gets full with data, what happens when I add more data to the servers. Will the balancer know that the first is full and transfer the extra data from the first server to the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The balancer will try to evenly partition the chunks on all shards.

First, your first largest shard will not get filled first. Along time you will probably have a similar amount of chunks and data on both shards. This is why it is recommended to have similar server specs.

Nevertheless, if you want to partition your chunks in a ratio of two to one you can do one of the two:

- [Change the Maximum Storage Size for a Given Shard](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-sharded-cluster-balancer/#sharded-cluster-config-max-shard-size) . Use a ratio of 2 to 1
- [Use Tag Aware Sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/tag-aware-sharding/) , which is more manageable, predictable option

Comment: To be more specific: if for example you set the maxsize as 400 (MB) for your smaller server, the balancer will stop migrating chucks to it, once this limit is crossed. By ratio I meant: set the smaller server maxsize to 400 and optionally the larger server to 800

Comment: @TasostheGreat Also note: "Also, the balancer will not move chunks off an overloaded shard. This must happen manually". This is important if you decide to add a third shard for example.

Comment: what does it mean that it should happen manually, I mean what if like you said I add a third shard, and I keep adding data, but I've reached the 400MB limit, will the database function correctly? Will the new data just be added to the third and second shard for example which are free? Or will the balancer try to add more new data to the first shard (due to sharding) and I would have to move the new data manually out of the first to the third shard. Can I just put a maxsize and then just keep adding new shards when the whole database size increases? Would that work?

Comment: Manually means you will have to call the `moveChuck` command on a shard you've set maxsize on in case you remove this shard, or you want to re-balance (possibly to new shard added). The cluster however will function correctly, adding data /moving chunks for the other two shards. Basically yes, you can just add more shards (even when you set maxsize to one of them) when your data size increases, which you should do either way.